# why does pgeom n parameter value need to be one less than I expected?

Tags: r

There is an example question in the book Head First Statistics:

> 20% of cereal packets contain a free toy. What’s the probability
>   you’ll need to open fewer than 4 cereal packets before finding your
>   first toy?

The worked solution is given as:

```
P(X ≤ 3) 
= 1 - q^r
= 1 - 0.8^3
= 1 - 0.512 
= 0.488
```

I would have expected to use the following R statement:

```
> pgeom(3, 0.2)
[1] 0.5904
```

But as you can see the answer isn't as expected.  The correct value for the n parameter is 2 as can be seen below:

```
> pgeom(2, 0.2)
[1] 0.488
```

Can someone explain why this is the case and where I am thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would be interested in knowing the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this. My text book and pgeom use different density functions. From the documentation, pgeom uses p(x) = p*(1-p)^x, my book uses p(x) = p*(1-p)^(x-1). Presumably Head First uses the latter formula too.

Answer (score 3):

The question says "fewer than 4".

So, if you consider a max of 3 tries, then the number of failures is `2` before you get the free toy and from documentation:

`pgeom(q, prob, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)`  where

`q`: "*vector of quantiles representing the number of failures in a sequence of Bernoulli trials before success occurs*"

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter in *pgeom* would be the number of failed trials.

Your question asks the probability of finding a toy in less than 4 packets. So you can either find a toy in packet 1,2 or 3. That means either 1 or 2 failed trials can occur but not 3 (because your 3rd packet is a success event).

P.S: I'm taking an intro level stat course and faced a similar confusion. This is what I've convinced myself.